# How to get $(ab)1 = (a1)(b1)$ in Galois field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I'm reading Galois field from textbook *Groups, Matrices, and Vector Spaces - A Group Theoretic Approach to Linear Algebra* by James B. Carrell.

[image]
[image]

Here $r,a,b \in \mathbb N$ and $1 \in \mathbb F$.

While I understand $(ab)1 = a(b1)$, I could not get $(ab)1 = (a1)(b1)$. Clearly, $(ab)1$ means we sum $1 \in \mathbb F$ repeatedly $ab$ times, whereas $(a1)(b1)$ means the multiplication of $a1 \in \mathbb F$ and $b1 \in\mathbb F$.

Could you please elaborate on this equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the distributive property, we have
$$
(a1)(b1) = (\overbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}^{a \text{ times}})(b1) = 
\overbrace{b1 + \cdots + b1}^{a \text{ times}} = a(b1) = (ab)1.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it.